# Unit testing Rx Catch

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, system.reactive

I'm unit testing the following service and the issue is that I'm able to test only the happy path but not the unhappy path. So how do I test them? TestScheduler? http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html

These lines are left untested:

```cs
.Catch<string, TimeoutExceptiocn>(_ => Observable.Return("Timeout"))
.Catch<string, Exception>(ex => Observable.Return(ex.Message))
```

[image]

```cs
public interface IProductService
{
    Task<string> GetAsync();
}

public sealed class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public ProductService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public Task<string> GetAsync()
    {
        return Observable
            .FromAsync(() => _httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e307edf3200005d00858b49"))
            .SubscribeOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .Retry(5)
            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"Is message successful? {x.IsSuccessStatusCode}"))
            .SelectMany(async responseMessage =>
            {
                var response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return response;
            })
            .Catch<string, TimeoutException>(_ => Observable.Return("Timeout"))
            .Catch<string, Exception>(ex => Observable.Return(ex.Message))
            .ToTask();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class ProductServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetAsync_ShouldReturnText_WhenRequestIsSent()
    {
        // Arrange
        var messageHandler = new MockHttpMessageHandler("Stuff I want to return", HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
        var sut = new ProductService(httpClient);

        // Act
        var result = await sut.GetAsync();

        // Assert
        result.Should().Be("Stuff I want to return");
    }

    // TODO: Unhappy path
}
```

Comment: modify the mocked handler to be able to throw the expected exception to satisfy the test case

Comment: Just a side note: rewrite your `SelectMany` like this: `.SelectMany(responseMessage => Observable.FromAsync(() => responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()))`